# SSH client from jenkins not terminating even after build is success

Tags: jenkins, ssh, ant

I am running ant build on remote linux box using jenkins SSH plugin.
Issue here is, SSH connection is not getting closed. I mean job is not getting terminated even after build is successful. It keeps running without any console output.

Please let me know what might be the cause or how to fix this issue.

Thanks,
Ganesha

Comment: What commands are run on the remote system through ssh?

Comment: Please post the commands. I encountered same case. As it turns out the command I'm executing is not terminating even when executed in the target host.

Comment: command:-
ant int2_jenkins -DSOURCE='$QOAQUOTING_CHECKOUT_DIR' -DQOA_COMMON_SOURCE='$Q_COMMON_CHECKOUT_DIR'

environment variables for build:-
QOAQUOTING_CHECKOUT_DIR=/prod/qcquoting/checkout/2018_DEC/qoaquoting
Q_COMMON_CHECKOUT_DIR=/prod/qcquoting/checkout/2018_DEC/qoacommon